# jQuery variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, variables

Is there a way to pass jQuery variables to PHP variables and from PHP to jQuery?
I want to take and ID from a div (wich is generated with PHP) with jQuery and give that value to a variable.

Comment: yes, learn AJAX (and possibly jquery ajax)

Comment: There are literally _thousands_ of questions on this topic.  Look at those listed in the Related section of the sidebar as a start.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+pass+javascript+variable+to+php

Comment: What makes the div different from other elements in the page, in order to select that div, you will need a unique selector, so what make it different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a Javascript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261113/passing-variable-javascript-into-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass jquery variables to php variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202070/how-to-pass-jquery-variables-to-php-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP to jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#<?php echo $elementId; ?>').hide();
    });
</script>
```

jQuery to PHP :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $.post('page.php', { var: 'value' }).done(function(data){
            // Do something
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use ajax in post or get 
here is an example

```
//Javascript file
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
   $.post('my_ajax_receiver.php', 'val=' + $(this).val(), function (response) {
      alert(response);
   });
});

//PHP file ajax_remote.php
<?php
   $value = $_POST['val'];
   echo "I got your value! $value";
?>
```

Comment: This seems to be a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5202083/1935077

Comment: If there's a helpful answer already on SO, it is best to just link there, rather than to duplicate it.